# Recover MX4 Ubuntu Edition

Tags: ubuntu-touch, meizu-mx4

This morning I received an OTA update (on rc-channel), so updated it. The phone booted and got to the boot-up page with the red dots showing boot-up in progress. There it stayed forever.

I booted into recovery mode by pressing the volume up key and the power button simultaneously. I get to the screen with the ubuntu icon in the middle of the screen.

I would like to flash a new image to the phone in order to rescue it. By googling, I have found that I should use some adb or fastboot commands.

But adb shows my device as being "offline":

```
# adb devices
List of devices attached 
75HABLLKLECR    offline
#
```

and fastboot doesn't list the device at all:

```
# fastboot devices
#
```

Thus, any fastboot commands passed on, like reboot, would tell me to wait for the device until I give up:

```
# fastboot reboot
< waiting for device >
^C
#
```

lsusb can find it though:

```
# lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 058f:9540 Alcor Micro Corp. AU9540 Smartcard Reader
Bus 003 Device 082: ID 2a45:0c01 Meizu Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 04ca:7035 Lite-On Technology Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 8087:07dc Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
#
```

and it shows in dmesg when connecting the USB-cable:

```
[92324.870437] usb 3-3: USB disconnect, device number 82
[92334.298510] usb 3-1: new high-speed USB device number 83 using xhci_hcd
[92334.525876] usb 3-1: New USB device found, idVendor=2a45, idProduct=0c01
[92334.525879] usb 3-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=4
[92334.525881] usb 3-1: Product: MX4
[92334.525882] usb 3-1: Manufacturer: Meizu
[92334.525883] usb 3-1: SerialNumber: 75HABLLKLECR
```

Does anybody know where to go from here? Why is the device "offline" as seen from adb? I suppose it's because it's in recovery mode, and thus the phone doesn't offer an adb API. What about fastboot? Isn't that a tool supposed to communicate with a phone in the recovery step?

Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: check out this stack overflow answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14993855/android-adb-device-offline-cant-issue-commands. You might find an answer that will solve this. I'd probably first try the `adb kill-server` then retry the `adb devices`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You went to `recovery`, not `fastboot`.

Get to recovery with `VolUp + Power`

Get to fastboot with `VolDown + Power`

I recommend flashing a custom recovery such as TWRP. You can make flashable partition backups (which are admittedly large, but you can put them on a USB given an OTG cable) that will absolutely save you from damaging updates/flashes.

Comment: Thank you. That solved the problem. I needed to go to fastboot, which I didn't know what was, to flash a new recovery image, which in turn would accept adb commands. Then the phone appeared online in the adb devices and I was able to reflash the phone. :)

Comment: @Ivar You are very welcome :)